# mysql chart AVG count orders per hour for the last month

Tags: php, mysql, charts

I am trying for a while to do a chart that calculate the average of orders per hour for the last month. 
I found some function that work on the workbench but not on chart, I need some help please.

- every row is an order.
- time column called "creation_time".

This is example for daily avg. It's working on the workbench but not on the chart:

```
SELECT day_of_week, AVG(order_count) average_order FROM 
(
  SELECT DAYNAME(creation_time) day_of_week, 
         DAYOFWEEK(creation_time) day_num, 
         TO_DAYS(creation_time) date,
         count(*) order_count
  FROM devsendi_dev.orders 
  GROUP BY date
) temp
GROUP BY day_of_week 
ORDER BY day_num
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hourly Average for 24 hours on the 30 days data :

```
SELECT hour_1, AVG(order_count) average_order FROM 
(
  SELECT 
        date(creation_time) as date_of_month,
        DAYNAME(creation_time) day_of_week, 
        DAYOFWEEK(creation_time) day_num, 

        HOUR(creation_time) hour_1,
        count(*) order_count
  FROM devsendi_dev.orders 
  where creation_time<=now() and creation_time>=date_sub(creation_time, interval 1 month)
  GROUP BY date_of_month,hour_1
) temp
GROUP BY hour_1 
ORDER BY hour_1
```

Hourly Average for 24 hours/weekday on the 30 days data :

```
SELECT day_of_week,hour_1, AVG(order_count) average_order,day_num FROM 
(
  SELECT 
        date(creation_time) as date_of_month,
        DAYNAME(creation_time) day_of_week, 
        DAYOFWEEK(creation_time) day_num, 

        HOUR(creation_time) hour_1,
        count(*) order_count
  FROM devsendi_dev.orders 
  where creation_time<=now() and creation_time>=date_sub(creation_time, interval 1 month)
  GROUP BY date_of_month,hour_1
) temp
GROUP BY day_of_week,hour_1  
ORDER BY day_num
```

Comment: First of all you are the man!!
it's work like a magic on the workbench.
but on the chart it's giving me error:

"There are syntax error in the query please find details below.
SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax:
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'SELECT * FROM orders
where creation_time<=now() and creation_time>=date_sub(' 
at line 10"

Comment: can you provide small part of code where you have placed sql??

Comment: i found the problem.
i was wrong in the name of the tabel